# Undefined reference to `rpl_sprintf',`rpl_printf' and `rpl_vfprintf' while cross compiling with aarch64-poky-linux-gcc

Tags: c, linux, gcc, cross-compiling

I'm trying to cross-compile a multi-file C program with aarch64-poky-linux-gcc compiler in a qemu environment emulating the RCAR H3 board, but I am getting multiple error messages of the type:

> print_logs.c:(.text+0xb30): undefined reference to `rpl_sprintf`

> /opt/poky/3.1.8/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/aarch64-poky-linux/gcc/aarch64-poky-linux/9.3.0/real-ld: print_logs.c:(.text+0xba8): undefined reference to `rpl_vfprintf`

> /opt/poky/3.1.8/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/aarch64-poky-linux/gcc/aarch64-poky-linux/9.3.0/real-ld: /tmp/ccQCq6cr.o: in function `GetTimeString`:
> print_logs.c:(.text+0xcb0): undefined reference to `rpl_sprintf`

> /opt/poky/3.1.8/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/aarch64-poky-linux/gcc/aarch64-poky-linux/9.3.0/real-ld: /tmp/ccDkm6Zr.o: in function `DBusServerCreateAndRun`:
> dbus_api.c:(.text+0xf0): undefined reference to `rpl_printf`

These errors seem to originate only from some of the C files even though printf,sprintf and vfprintf have been used in multiple other files(I have also used these functions in a sample helloworld program which also does not give any of these errors on cross-compiling). I did not face this error when cross compiling the code with the arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc cross-compiler.

Comment: Perhaps your recipe is missing a build dependency for whatever library implements those `rpl_` functions. Or perhaps the `-L` and/or `-l` compiler options for the recipe have not been set correctly.